# single quotes or not in square bracket data?

Tags: php, database, quote, apostrophe

I have a (probably) very simple and easy to answer question, which I cannot find the answer to anywhere, perhaps it is too simple, and I am not well-versed in php.

I am using a script written by someone else, and they sometimes use single quotes within the square brackets, [ ], and sometimes not. What is the correct way?

For example, is it best written [data] or ['data']? I am a perfectionist and this is driving me crazy to know the proper method.

Echo "Name: " .$ratings['name']."";

$current = $ratings[total] / $ratings[votes]; 
 Echo "Current Rating: " . round($current, 1) . "";

Comment: This has been covered before, many times. There is no right way, just use whatever coding standard makes sense to you. Personally, I use `'` everywhere, unless I'm dealing with an actual string of text, then it's `"`

Comment: @MatW The question isn't asking about single vs. double quotes - it is asking about single vs. no quotes.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13622486/php-array-access-without-quotes - you may get a warning if you have errors turned on. non quoted attempts a constant first. If not found, it reads as a string. proper way would be to avoid errors. I quote them always.

Comment: And as an extra note you should always be developing with error reporting turned all the way up so you see every tiny thing PHP thinks may be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You must always use single or double quotes when accessing an array element.

I asked in ##php on freenode, and they believe this quirk existed [since PHP4.3](http://3v4l.org/5UBT4) (god knows why), but right now when PHP comes across `$array[value]`, it firstly tries to look for a constant named `value`, and if it is not `define()`'d, it treats the expression as `$array["value"]` and spit a Notice in PHP4. In PHP5, this has been upgraded to a warning.

In short: **Don't use it.** It confuses yourself.

Comment: so the answer i'm getting here is always use single quotes in square brackets i.e. ['data']...?

Comment: @user3175564 Correct.

Comment: Always with one exception. If the value inside the square brackets is a constant. ie. `$array[SOME_CONSTANT]` must not be put inside quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely use the quotes. Additionally, there is a subtle but important difference in PHP between single and double quotes strings. A single quoted string is actually faster, because it is treated as a literal, whereas a double quoted string gets interpreted, which takes O(n) time.  Example:

> $test = 'world';
>
> echo 'hello\n$test';

yields `hello\n$test`

> $test = 'world';
>
> echo "hello\n$test";

yields

> hello
>
> world

Answer (score 0):

Either double or single would work. Personally I prefer single.

PHP is very forgiving and only spits out a notice if no quotes are given to an index of the array.

Comment: It's no longer so forgiving with php 7.2, now showing warnings and code will fail with future php versions.